# Running an exe file on the azure

Tags: python, django, azure, azure-devops

I am working on an azure web app and inside the web app, I use python code to run an exe file. The webapp recieves certain inputs (numbers) from the user and stores those inputs in in a text file. Afterwards, an exe file would run and read the inputs and generate another text file, called "results". The problem is that although the code works fine on my local computer, as soos as I put it on azure, the exe file does not get triggered by the following line of code:

```
subprocess.call('process.exe',cwd = case_directory.path, shell= True)
```

I even tried running the exe file on Azure manually from the Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online) by "running from Console" option. It just did not do anything. I'd appreciate if anyone can help me.

Comment: Make sure you have added the complete filepath, otherwise provide more details.

Comment: I am sure about the path and also as I said when I call the exe file from Consol it does not work either. Same file works and generates the txt file as its supposed to do on my local computer.

Comment: Show what you have done, provide as much detail as you can...if you ask a vague question all you can expect are vague answers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at using a [WebJob](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-webjobs-resources/) to host\run your executable from? A WebJob can be virtually any kind of script or win executable. There are a number of ways to trigger your WebJob. You also get a lot of buit in monitoring and logging for free as well, via the [Kudu](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Web-jobs) interface.

Answer (score 0):

@F.K I searched some information which may be helpful for you, please see below.

1. Accroding to the python document for [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module, `Using shell=True can be a security hazard.` Please see the warning under [Frequently Used Arguments](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) for details.
2. There is a comment in the [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-python-configure/) which gave a direction for the issue, please see the screenshot below.

[image]

However, normally, the recommended way to satisfy your needs is using Azure [Queue](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-python-how-to-use-queue-storage/) & [Blob](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-python-how-to-use-blob-storage/) Storage & Azure [WebJobs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-webjobs-readme/) to save the input file into a storage queue, and handling the files got from queue and save the result files into blob storage by a continuous webjob.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Really helped

Comment: I am learning about the wejobs. The problem I have is that the exe file I have, looks for the input text file only in its own directory and also generates the result in the same directory so it makes problem with storing the inputs in the Queue and also the result in the Blob storage.

Comment: @F.K OK. Could you post a new thread for your problem with using Azure Storage Queue & Blob? It will be very helpful for describing the details and replying the solution. Thanks! Please tell me the new thread link.